# How does listx2 = [x * 2 | x<- numberList] work?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

So  I m watching a very basic Tutorial, and I m at list comprehension where this comes up:

```
listx2 = [x * 2 | x<- numberList]
```

with numberList being a list of numbers

So this takes every number in the list and duplicates it, so `numberList = [1,2]` results in `[2,4]`.

But HOW does the whole Syntax come together?

I know that x * 2 is the doubleing, but the rest just doesn't make sense to me.

`|` is the "or" Symbol as far as I know,and what does it do there?

`x <- numberList` gives `x` a number from the list, but why does it take just a number? and why so nicely one after the other? There is no recursion or anything that tells it to do one element at a time...

I learn stuff by understanding it, so is that even possible here or do I just have to accept this as "thats how it goes" and memorize the pattern?

Comment: This should all be explained in any tutorial on list comprehensions. Have you looked one up?

Comment: And as for why the exact syntax is used, like a lot of other aspects of Haskell, it's borrowed from math. I think it's pulled from set theory where `o ∈ A` means that `o` is a member of the set `A`. Haskell is using an arrow in place of `∈`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions use their own special syntax, which is

```
[ e | q1, q2, ..., qn ]
```

The `|` is not an "or", it's part of the syntax, just as `[` and `]`.

Each `qi` can be of the following forms.

- `x <- list` chooses `x` from the `list`
- `condition` is a boolean expression, which discards the `x`s chosen before if the `condition` is false
- `let y = expression` defines variable `y` accordingly

Finally, `e` is an expression which can involve all the variables defined in the `qi`, and which forms the elements in the resulting list.

Comment: Thanks, that went right into my cheat sheet.
For any other people seeking an example on the condition, here is a function returning the odd numbers from a list:
oddList = [x  |x <- numberList  , (mod x 2 ==1) ]

Where (mod x 2 ==1) is the condition

Answer (score 2):

What you see is *syntactical sugar*. So Haskell does *not* interpret the pipe (`|`) as a guard, etc. It sees the list comprehension as a whole.

This however does *not* mean that the `<-` are picked at random. Actually list comprehension maps nicely on the *list monad*. What you see is syntactical sugar for:

```
listx2 = do
    x <- numberList
    return x*2
```

Now a list type `[]` is actually a monad. It means that we have written:

```
listx2 = numberList >>= \x -> return (x*2)
```

Or even shorter:

```
listx2 = numberList >>= return . (*2)
```

Now the list monad is defined as:

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    xs >>= k = concat $ fmap k xs
```

So this means that it is equivalent to:

```
listx2 = numberList >>= return . (*2)
listx2 = concat (fmap (return . (*2)) numberList)
listx2 = concat (fmap (\x -> [2*x]) numberList)
```

Now for a list `fmap` is equal to `map`, so:

```
listx2 = concat $ map (\x -> [2*x]) numberList
listx2 = concatMap (\x -> [2*x]) numberList
```

so that means that for every element `x` in the `numberList` we will generate a singleton list `[2*x]` and concatenate all these singleton lists into the result.